# Adding another Namenode to HDP HA Cluster

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, high-availability, hdp

I have HDP3 High Availability enabled on the cluster. I have tested it and everything seems to be fine.

> Current Setup is `nn1 (Active), nn2 (Passive)`

Now, I am trying to add another NameNode, which makes this setup from `NN1, NN2` to

> `NN1, NN2 (Passive), NN3 (Passive)`.

If we look at the steps that are needed from Apache documentation as :

- [Apache documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.0.3/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSHighAvailabilityWithNFS.html#Configuration_details)

or From Cloudera/Hortonworks:

- [Configuring the namenode HA cluster](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.0/fault-tolerance/content/configuring_the_namenode_ha_cluster.html)
- [Deploying namenode HA cluster](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.0/fault-tolerance/content/deploying_namenode_ha_cluster.html)

and particularly followed, Step 7 for new namenode

I change configurations as

> dfs.ha.namenodes.mycluster = `nn1,nn2,nn3`
>
> dfs.namenode.http-address.mycluster.nn3 = `vmhdpmaster003:50070`
>
> dfs.namenode.https-address.mycluster.nn3 = `vmhdpmaster003:50470`
>
> dfs.namenode.rpc-address.mycluster.nn3 = `vmhdpmaster003:8020`
>
> dfs.namenode.shared.edits.dir = `qjournal://vmhdpmaster003:8485;vmhdpmaster001:8485;vmhdpmaster002:8485/mycluster`

After applying the changes., I don't see `nn3` added as another namenode.

So then I tried,

`su -l hdfs -c "hdfs namenode -bootstrapStandby -force`

Now, I am getting an error like nn/vmhdpmaster003@REALM.com is able to get ticket, because there is no keytab file at /etc/security/keytabs. My cluster is configured with AD integration.

Please help me how to create this missing keytab. Why ambari does not create a keytab itself? Is there a way to generate keytabs for service accounts via curl for ambari?